# Add button to navigationBarTitle Swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Im working in swift ui. I want to put a button on the side of the NavigationBar title.

I want to be able to click the user image and navigate to another view

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve.]

Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Se eg here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-bar-items-to-a-navigation-view

Answer (score 2):

The buttons are placed in navigation bar using `.navigationBarItems()`. Any view can be used inside a `Button`, so a button almost like the one in your image can be declared like this:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {

        // the rest of your UI components

        .navigationBarTitle("Browse")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {}) {
                                VStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Image("name")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                }
                            })
    }
}
```

Please note that it has a slightly different alignment (is going to get drawn a bit higher than your example).

Comment: I have noticed the alignement is a little off

Comment: There's unfortunately nothing you can do about it. The buttons in navigation bar are aligned to the top. The Spacer() pushes it down as far as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem with the offset, but it is very hacky. And maybe there is a better answer to your problem than this. But if you are ok with this answer please give LuLuGaGa an upvote as I have copied a lot from him. And I did not come up with that answer myself, but I can not remember where I found the original answer.

```
NavigationView {

    // the rest of your UI components

    .navigationBarTitle("") // To hide the real navigationBarTitle
    .navigationBarItems(leading:
        Text("Browse").font(.largeTitle).bold().padding(.top, 10), // To add a fake navigationBarTitle
        trailing: Button(action: {}) {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image("swiftui")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
        } .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // You should also add that to your code otherwise the picture will turn blue
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var body: some View {
NavigationView {
    Text("SwiftUI")
        .navigationBarTitle("Welcome")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button("Bar button") {
                print("Bar button!")
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you could explain why your code would solve the problem. Either try to explain your steps or include parts of documentation with reference to the original.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
NavigationView{
    .navigationBarTitle("Browse")
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        Button(action: { // Move to next View }){
            Image()
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: OP is asking solution for SwiftUI.