# In SwiftUI, is there a way to display a "profile" image in navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)?

Tags: swiftui

When using an Image in `navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)`, these are the results:

1. Success - `Image(systemName: "plus")`
2. Success - `Image("iconProfile")` where "iconProfile" is an image asset (pdf) of 4 KB
3. Failure - `Image("photoProfile")` where "photoProfile" is an image asset (jpeg) of 400 KB

I am trying to get item 3 to work. It will only display a view of solid color. Does anyone know whether there is a image type or size limit in what can be rendered in `navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)`?

Edit: This is different to the item suggested by @LuLuGaGa in the comment below. That question deals with adding an image to `navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)`, whereas my question relates specifically to the **rendering** of an asset already added to `navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add button to navigationBarTitle Swift ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999824/add-button-to-navigationbartitle-swift-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, images in nav bars have a `TemplateRenderingMode` of `.template`, meaning they will only look at the alpha channel. They are monochromatic and the tint color. If you have an asset that has actual color that you want to display, then you need to set the template rendering mode to `.original`.

```swift
Image("lol")
    .resizable()
    .renderingMode(.original)
```

Edit:
Just noticing you are using a JPEG, which has no alpha channel (transparency) and so if this is your failure case, and therefore you intend for it to appear more as an icon, then you might just want to switch to a PNG.